# Install the .net Framework 4.0 from web automatically when needed

Tags: c#, .net, wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

I have a wix installer from my C# application. So far configuration is like this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

  <Product Id="*" Name="My App Name" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0"
           Manufacturer="My Name" UpgradeCode="GUID-HERE">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL" />
    <Condition Message=".net Framework 4.0 is needed.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR (NETFRAMEWORK40FULL)]]>
    </Condition>
```

So far if .net Framework 4.0 not installed the installation stops with a warning message box.

But instead preventing the installation to continue the installer offer to user install .net Framework 4.0 from web.

There is any way to do this?

Comment: There's [a lot of coverage](https://www.google.com/search?q=wix+installer+net+framework) on Stack Overflow for this issue already.  Are you sure your question isn't already answered?

Comment: I am looking for hours and not found a way to do this. I found how incorporate the .net installer in my msi (using standard alone), but not with web instalation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include .NET framework package in a WiX bootstrapped installer for clients without an internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052941/how-to-include-net-framework-package-in-a-wix-bootstrapped-installer-for-client)